# High Charts Data Table not filtering data by range selector

Tags: javascript, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I am using highcharts for charts. I have enabled the export feature and it has one option view data table. When you click on it shows a data table below the chart. The problem I am facing is that if I select a particular value from the Range selector the view data table still shows a complete dataset. The range selector has no effect on it.
How can I only display data that is given upon selecting a particular range selector value?

For example, if I have selected data for the last minutes and the chart is showing data for the 10 mins the data table should also show data for the last 10 mins, It should not display the entire dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this feature is not implemented in the Highstock. The data table takes all data by default, but the option which you want to have will be a really nice functionality. Could you report this idea on the Highcharts Github issue channel as a feature request?

Link: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues